# How to Get ASIHTTPRequest Involved In My Own Program?

Tags: objective-c, http, macos, asihttprequest

I have run ASIHTTPRequest successfully. I got it from the link, http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tarball/master.

Since I just started to learn xCode, I am not sure how to get ASIHTTPRequest involved in my Objective-C programs. I am familiar with Java and .NET. A mature library is packaged into .jar and  .dll in Java and .NET, respectively. In XCode, the corresponding library should be .dylib? But I didn't find it.

I am reading XCode tutorials. Hope I could solve it. Could you give me a hint?

Thanks,
LB

Comment: Please accept answers that solve your problems! Just mark checkbox underneath the voting count of the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try docs investigation here:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions

Answer (score 2):

iOS does not allow you to include custom frameworks, which is why many libraries that are intended to be used on i-devices are shipped as .h and .m files that you can include in your project.  Open source projects tend to go this route since they're not trying to keep the code secret or proprietary.

That being said, there is a way to include compiled libraries, .a files, in an iOS project.  Closed source projects, like Google Analytics, go this route because it doesn't provide visibility under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

In all of the open source libraries I have implemented in XCode, the code has always been provided in its raw form, not packaged into a library like in .NET/Java.

I am using ASIHTTPRequest in my project, and I simply added the code files from the github download into my project as a group and referenced ASIHTTPRequest.h to begin using the functionality.